# Is there any alternative plugin for UIPicker view?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using cordova ionic for mobile app development, I need to show `uipickerview` in my app. So i am using the following plugin:

https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-pickerview

But I am getting an error message like the below:

> Installing "org.apache.cordova.plugins.PickerView" for ios
>
> Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
>
> Failed to install 'org.apache.cordova.plugins.PickerView':Error: Uh oh!
>
> "/Users/munavvar/MQSD/footer/plugins/org.apache.cordova.plugins.PickerView/PickerView.m" not found!

Comment: This plugin has not been updated since sep 2013, neither they are tracking issues. Same [issue](https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-pickerview/issues/10) has already been logged. I will suggest you not to use this. As they are no more giving support to it.

Comment: Thanks A lot. can you please suggest me any other plugin for this one. it would be a great help

Comment: Yes i can if you tell me what exactly is your purpose? and what behavior are you looking for.

Comment: i have a textfield  while clicking on that i need to list a a group of peoples name from server. the client need ios native picker for listing the names.

Comment: soory but I do not have knowledge of other such plugin to get native picker. You should edit your question to ask alternative too. So others can help.

Comment: sure thanks a lot ...

Comment: Find here very simple demo of UI PickerView in ionic http://codepen.io/PeacePan/pen/PPvYqL?editors=1100

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the answer. No need to use the plugin, just use the below code:

```
<div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input item-select">
        <div class="input-label">
            Lightsaber
        </div>
        <select>
            <option>Blue</option>
            <option selected>Green</option>
            <option>Red</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Simple and elegant solution. Cordova Platform converts <select> to a UIPickerView for iOS Platform and for Android it is converted to a Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

As plugin mentioned by you have no more support, use this one, it will fulfill your purpose:
https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0
It is a combination of UIPickerView and UIActionSheet. And it also gives options for customization.

Comment: Hi Mudassar, This one looks promising. But as I dont have much native iOS experience, how should we use the same in Cordova???